# I would like to to react router to render a new page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

i got this code working as expected (somewhat)

```
**App.js**
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import MyForm from "./Recpayfrm";
function App() {
  return (
    // Code taken from https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start
    <Router>
      <div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/Recpayfrm">MyForm</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/users">Users</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

        {/* A <Switch> looks through its children <Route>s and
          renders the first one that matches the current URL. */}
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/Recpayfrm">
            <MyForm />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/users">
            <Users />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
function Home() {
  return <h2>Home</h2>;
}
function Users() {
  return <h2>Users</h2>;
}
export default App;
```

but when the link MyForm is clicked, the results show at the bottom (ie the HOME area).
I would like a fresh page to rendered/displayed. See the input field at the pict.

How do i render/display a fresh page of the component MyForm in the Recpayfrm.js?
[image]

Comment: So you want it to be displayed in it's own page without the navbar list you have?

Comment: Hope this helps - https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-wave-k3qcq?file=/src/App.js

Comment: i would like to. but for now i would settle for a new page. need to take things at nibble size for now. Thank you for the sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can encapsulate all the routes that need to be in the ***"Home Area"*** (have the navbar list) inside a `HomeComponent` for instance.
And those who need a "fresh page" outside, like so:

```
// Every route here will also contain the navbar
function HomeComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/Recpayfrm">MyForm</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/users">Users</Link>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <Switch>
            <Route path="/users">
                <Users/>
            </Route>
            <Route path="/">
                <Home/>
            </Route>
        </Switch>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Now in your `App` component you will add all the routes that need to be rendered in their own page:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/Recpayfrm">
                <MyForm/>
            </Route>
            <Route path="/">
                <HomeComponent/>
            </Route>
        </Switch>
    </Router>
  )
}
```

[Here it is](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-pine-j5ibt?file=/src/App.js) in action

Comment: Thank You. sorry but need to ask you more,  the function HomeComponent should be in another .js file?

Comment: Its up to you. Usually components should be in their own .js files, and then you import them wherever you need

Comment: I added a sandbox for you to see it, check my original answer again